# brownian motion calculus

Tags: probability

How to show $\int_0^t 1_{B_s=0}dB_s=0$?

I have tried:
$\int_0^t 1_{B_s=0}dB_s=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1_{B_{t_i}=0}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}B_{t_{i+1}}$ but it's not equal 0

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Compute $\Bbb E\left[\left(\int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}}\,dB_s\right)^2\right]$.